# How to know if the pointer is going to left or right in ionic-angular range component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-components

I wan’t to know if there is a way to find pointer direction on ionic range component. I mean if pointer is going to left or right?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What did you try? If i were you i would inspect ionChange event to see if it contains what you need, if not directly you can calculate delta between values and conclude where its going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here is how you can do it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qnxrnv

Basically you have your range (I used default one which is 0 to 100 values):

And you bind method to detect the movement:

```
sliderValueChanged(event) {
    // if current slider value exist we can do comparision:
    if (this.currentSliderValue && (this.currentSliderValue > event.value)) {
      console.log("moving left");
    } else {
      console.log("moving right")
    }
    // now we capture result
    this.currentSliderValue = event.value
  }
```

Depending on your use case you may need to account for different situations when value equals etc etc

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what i'm seeking!